# Vega-lite line mark show tooltip at a distance

Tags: visualization, vega-lite, vega

I have the following chart in VegaLite:

([open in vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AGVMbKAGsABDk1Q1ZtgDMzYswBU4sMwGE2CHElk0bNlJ1FxoEOEpFFSRMFFRQBnVBNGjYziNTCEooCGIQAF8lZHUTNFBMAE8cOBThWRqlIzZBHRw0THUGOEKQOFkoNmUaWTIykAAPMbsAwWUU5RiGkErqlMxEHDZ1JGSeiqmZufRLGmsolZr0AEcGPx1YnVICpQHBLYO4WZSICoQmZvOVUuIFk3mGOwK+XyQA))

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Stock prices of 5 Tech Companies over Time.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "mark": {"type": "line", "tooltip": true},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

Notice the `"tooltip": true` - I want to be able to show the values on mouse hover. However, for the tooltip to show up, I have to hover my cursor exactly at the single pixel of the lines' data points.

I would like to show the tooltip already at some distance, let's say 20 pixels. Or even just anywhere, using the nearest data point. Is that possible without a lot of extra code in the spec? I especially want to avoid listing all the values from the legend, like [here](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_multi_line_pivot_tooltip.html).

I'd also like for the tooltip approach to work with multiple layers, e.g. in a combined line+bar chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the "nearest" attribute to a selection parameter. There are some limitations and workarounds documented here for your use case.

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html#nearest

Edit:

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Stock prices of 5 Tech Companies over Time.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": {"type": "line"}},
    {
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "paintbrush",
          "select": {"type": "point", "on": "mouseover", "nearest": true}
        }
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "tooltip": true},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "param": "paintbrush",
            "field": "symbol",
            "type": "ordinal"
          },
          "value": "transparent"
        },
        "size": {"value": 75}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I already went through these docs but it didn't help me how to create a tooltip for line charts. Could you modify my example spec to show an example?

Comment: I'll show you now.

Comment: This is great, thank you! However, it seems to stop working when I add `timeUnit` to the X channel and `aggregate` to the Y channel: [vega editor](https://shorturl.at/eqJPT). Any idea how to make it work with an aggregation?

Comment: I would ask a different question and mark this one as solved as the original question has been answered.